# Make a custom openshift catridge with php7.0

Tags: php, openshift, php-7

On Openshift there is an oudated version of php therefore I want to make a catridge that is able to run the latest php version in order to run applications that require the latesr version of it.

I also need to have composer intalled too and to be able to connect either with mysql/mariadb or postgresql.

I have seen https://blog.openshift.com/new-openshift-cartridge-format-part-1/ and https://blog.openshift.com/new-openshift-cartridge-format-part-2/ from documentation and I have just made the directory in order to make the compiles.

Also on the example abode does not show HOW to make a catridge when you need to customly compile stuff such as php.

So what I am asking is if I need to compile an x-y application that my application uses such as php7 etc etc how I will do it. Also php7 need to be compiled only once and I am not sure if I put my scripts on ./openshift/build is a good idea.

I also need to be able to manually abb composer and pecl support and to be able to use the existing postgresql and mysql catridges.

Comment: I made one a couple of months ago. It is still updated and maintained today. https://github.com/pinodex/openshift-cartridge-nginx-php7

Comment: If I want appache and not nginx?